Is it possible to extract apk and zip it again using build.gradle?
I'm doing a task to encrypt the dex files. Below code I wrote in build.gradle for encrypting and compress it back as apk.
applicationVariants.all { variant ->
        variant.outputs.each { output ->
            // Hook into the package task
            tasks.named("package${variant.name.capitalize()}").configure { packageTask ->
                packageTask.doLast {
                    println "Accessing source files before ZIP step"

                    def apkFile = output.outputFile
                    if (!apkFile.exists()) {
                        throw new GradleException("APK file does not exist: ${apkFile}")
                    }

                    def tmpDir = new File(buildDir, "tmp/renamedDexFiles")
                    if (tmpDir.exists()) {
                        tmpDir.deleteDir()
                    }
                    tmpDir.mkdirs()
                    // Extract APK
                    copy {
                        from zipTree(apkFile)
                        into tmpDir
                    }
                    def metaDir = new File(buildDir, "tmp/renamedDexFiles/META-INF")
                    if (metaDir.exists()) {
                        metaDir.deleteDir()
                    }

                    // Rename dex files in the temporary directory
                    tmpDir.listFiles().each { dexFile ->
                        if (dexFile.name.startsWith("classes") && dexFile.name.endsWith(".dex")) {
                            def containApplicationClass = containsApplicationClass(dexFile)
                            if (containApplicationClass) {
//                                dexFile.renameTo("${dexFile.parent}/CrashRestartApp.dex")
                            } else {
//                                def encryptingFilePath = "${dexFile.parent}/${dexFile.name}.enc"
//
//                                javaexec {
//                                    classpath = files("${buildDir}/intermediates/javac/debug/classes")
//                                    main = 'brightree.encryptor.DexEncryptor'
//                                    println(dexFile)
//                                    args dexFile, encryptingFilePath, secretKeyPath
//                                }
                            }
//                            delete dexFile
                        }
                    }

                    def newApkFile = new File(buildDir, "outputs/apk/debug/ant.zip.apk")
                    ant.zip(destfile: newApkFile, basedir: tmpDir)
                }
            }
        }
    }

But after zip back apk and sign, I can't install it. It always returns message "App not installed" without any other errors. Is there anyone who did that before? Please advise. Much appreciated!
